# c++ initializing a binary tree node

Tags: c++, tree, binary

I get these errors: e0289 no instance of constructor...matches argument list and c2440: 'initializing' cannot convert from initializer list to BinaryTreeNod

I am trying to point head to left and right subtree.

---

```
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct BinaryTreeNode{
  T data;
  unique_ptr<BinaryTreeNode<T>> left, right;

  explicit BinaryTreeNode(const T& data) : data(data) {}
  BinaryTreeNode(T data, unique_ptr<BinaryTreeNode<T>> left,
  unique_ptr<BinaryTreeNode<T>> right) : data(data), left(move(left)),
  right(move(right)) {}
};

int main()
{

  BinaryTreeNode<int> subtree_0{ 5 };
  BinaryTreeNode<int> subtree_1{ 7 };
  BinaryTreeNode<int> head{3, subtree_0, subtree_1 };
}
```

---

the error comes from the line *BinaryTreeNode head{3, subtree_0, subtree_1 };*. Is something wrong with the constructor? Or am I doing smth wrong trying to initialize like that?
Just trying to make a simple binary tree (the code of the BinaryTree Node is from "Elements of Programming Interviews"

Comment: Did you try `BinaryTreeNode<int> head{3, &subtree_0, &subtree_1 };`? Though, a `std::unique_ptr` want's to take ownership (and `delete` the instances when going out of scope). That's a bad idea for local variables.

Comment: In this case, a possible fix would be to create the instances `subtree_0` and `subtree_1` with `new` and store them as raw pointers. You may also consider `std::make_unique` but then you have to move them in the call as well.

Comment: Scheff Yes I did, does not work.

Comment: _Yes I did, does not work._ There is probably no implicit conversion from raw pointer to `std::unique_ptr`. (Have to look into the doc...) Yes. It's explicit: [std::unique_ptr::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr). (It's _(3)_.)

Comment: I once made a sample to handle things with `std::unique_ptr`s where instances may be passed as well as temporaries. (It uses the deleter option of the `std::unique_ptr` to achieve this.) [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae17e076a5a0830c). It allows nice usage but comes with a little bit effort... Additionally, in my productive work, I had derived classes of course. As taking ownership of a temporary requires a copy I had to add a "virtual copy constructor" aka. a `virtual` clone method to the pointee class.

Comment: The linked demo in my previous comment was my "proof of concept". I later made another [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bfe6ee27f59116d) for how it looks in productive use. (It contains the `virtual` clone method I mentioned.)

Answer (score 2):

[`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) does not support implicit pointer to unique pointer conversion, but it has an explicit constructor to do so. But assigning it a stack allocated pointer is not advised as it might try to delete it later on.

To resolve this, we need to make the two nodes out of unique pointers.

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<BinaryTreeNode<int>> subtree_0 = std::make_unique<BinaryTreeNode<int>>(BinaryTreeNode<int>(5));
std::unique_ptr<BinaryTreeNode<int>> subtree_1 = std::make_unique<BinaryTreeNode<int>>(BinaryTreeNode<int>(7));
```

But as the spec states, you cannot copy any unique pointers. Which means that we need to move these two pointers to the tree node object. For this we need to accept them as [rvalues](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) in the constructor. Then we can move the pointers to the object without an issue.

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct BinaryTreeNode {
    ...
    BinaryTreeNode(T data, std::unique_ptr<BinaryTreeNode<T>>&& left,
        std::unique_ptr<BinaryTreeNode<T>>&& right) : data(data), left(std::move(left)), right(std::move(right)) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<BinaryTreeNode<int>> subtree_0 = std::make_unique<BinaryTreeNode<int>>(BinaryTreeNode<int>(5));
    std::unique_ptr<BinaryTreeNode<int>> subtree_1 = std::make_unique<BinaryTreeNode<int>>(BinaryTreeNode<int>(7));
    BinaryTreeNode<int> head{ 3, std::move(subtree_0), std::move(subtree_1) };
}
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot! I simply did not know this way of intitializing with make shared, also, making it rvalue && is a relatively new concept to me. It did fix the error, However, now I get a new error: C2280 std::unique_ptr<BinaryTreeNode<int>,std::default_delete<BinaryTreeNode<int>>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<BinaryTreeNode<int>,std::default_delete<BinaryTreeNode<int>>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

Comment: @kanulilewa Are you sure that your moving in the pointers using `std::move`?

Comment: Positive. Just  copied and pasted the code from here to my program.

Comment: Okay found it, sorry I accidentally deleted 'move' from constructor

Comment: Thanks again D-Raj and Scheff - your help is priceless!